# Invalid file path or buffer object type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When running the below code I am getting the following error:

`Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Code:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from seaborn import lineplot
from matplotlib import pyplot
df = pd.read_csv("Sexo-Resultado.csv")
dataset = read_csv(df, header=0)
lineplot(x='Sexo', y='Resultado', data=dataset)
pyplot.show()
```

I believe the error is on the df?? the data only has two columns, Sexo and Resultado